# Speed up cosine similarity search in elasticsearch by filtering on angular distance of vectors to "space diagonal"

Tags: python, performance, elasticsearch, vector, cosine-similarity

I am currently trying to find a way to speed up searching for similar documents in an elasticsearch index that contains several 100 million documents.

All documents in the index have a dense vector field that contains a vector computed using Google's Multilingual Universal Sentence Encoder (MUSE).

The resulting vector for the document has 512 values and it always seems to be a unit vector, because the length of all vectors is already always 1 (when rounded to 6 decimal places).

Every single value of a vector lies between -0.165 and +0.165. (Values rounded)

To find similar documents we’re using cosine similarity. Without further filtering on additional criteria (e.g. publication period, author, contained keywords) a search for documents with a cosine similarity of e.g. 0.95 to a given document currently takes a bit more than 20 seconds.

elasticsearch recommends to always limit the search by cosine similarity by additional conditions.

But what, if I don't have any criteria for the text to compare (unknown author, unknown publication period, ...) ?

I already have an idea for a solution, but I don't know if it is mathematically tenable and therefore I need your expertise.

Assumption:

The vector space spanned by the MUSE vectors has an imaginary "space diagonal" running from the origin of the coordinate system to the "maximum" of the coordinate system.

This space diagonal is a vector which has a value of +0.165 in every point. Thus the unit vector to this space diagonal has +0.0442 in every point.  (All values rounded.)

For each vector of any document, the angular distance to the space diagonal can be determined when indexing and storing the document.

So far so good. Here’s what I am not sure about:

The angular distance between two document vectors that should be compared against each other can be calculated as the difference between the angular distance of each document to the space diagonal.

The angular distance between the two document vectors being compared must not exceed a value of X, if the cosine similarity of the two documents has to be a value of at least Y.

I have already checked this with a probe of 140,000 documents.

The result was

- for a cosine similarity of at least 0.95 maximum distance was 3.00 degrees
- for a cosine similarity of at least 0.90 maximum distance was 3.66 degrees
- for a cosine similarity of at least 0.85 maximum distance was 4.57 degrees
- for a cosine similarity of at least 0.80 maximum distance was 5.48 degrees

The maximum distance between two documents in the probe was 15.3 degrees.

So if I have a document with a distance of e.g. 6 degrees to the space diagonal I could filter for documents with distances in between 3 and 9 degrees to the space diagonal (given a cosine similarity of 0.95 requires a max distance between the document of 3.0 degrees (see above)) and thus could eliminate a large amount of candidates before elasticsearch needs to calculate the cosine similarity.

Before I now start to reindex several hundred million documents to store the distance to the space diagonal on the article, I would like to know if my idea is correct.
Anybody out there who feels competent to comment on this idea?